# CSS expression depending on text

Tags: css, colors

I have a paragraph like this

```
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, /* consectetur adipiscing elit. */ </p>
```

I want to have a CSS class that have a different font color for the text between `/*` and `*/`
Thanks for help!

Comment: I think i was clear enough ... i do not want to change the text between <p> tags. So no <span> <label> or so.

Comment: JavaScript solution works out right? Even if you have a CSS rule, you need to wrap the text to apply it. And, if you don't wanna change the HTML by yourself, you can use the JavaScript way right?

Comment: I don't get why you wouldn't want to add a <span> or something between the <p> tags. What advantage does it give you, not having them, and using /* */ instead?

Comment: because is a lot of html page that i must change ... using js is a solution but i must be carefully to not mess it up because there are some other parts with /* */ not in <p> tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `Expressions` to do this.

#### CSS / HTML Way, by inserting an element inside.

You can use this way:

```
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span class="comment">/* consectetur adipiscing elit. */</span> </p>
```

#### CSS:

```
p span.comment {color: #999;}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jNvSw/

#### Or, if you wanna do in the JavaScript way (uses jQuery, but it can also be done using pure JavaScript):

```
​$(document)​.ready(function(){
    $("p").html($("p").html().replace('/*', '<span class="comment">/*'));
    $("p").html($("p").html().replace('*/', '*/</span>'));
});​
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jNvSw/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <label class="classA"> /* consectetur adipiscing elit. */ </label></p>

<style>
.classA
{
font-size:12px;
font-family:Arial;
color:blue;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your markup (/**/) with `<span>` tags if possible, then assign class with appropriate color to them.

Answer (score 0):

You could hack it using the `:first-line` pseudo-element, assuming there's a linebreak:

```
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, /* consectetur adipiscing elit. */ </p>

p { color: grey;
p:first-line { color: black; }
```

Note that this answer is not to be taken seriously.